# Why Webpack parse less style used by a library in the node_modules and how to prevent that

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

I'm using the Antd react component library, and our project got bigger over time, so we decided to create a costume Webpack workflow to optimize the build time. the problem is Webpack parse Antd components and try to resolve .less file which is used by Antd and I don't use it in my project at all, and I don't customize Antd theme neither.

How should I config Webpack to avoid parsing Antd library and anything in node_modules?

this is my webpack.dev.config.ts file:

```js
import path from "path";
import { Configuration } from "webpack";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";

const config: Configuration = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  target: ["browserslist"],
  output: {
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        use: [
          {
            loader: "svg-url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    extensions: [
      ".js",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx",
      ".json",
      ".jsx",
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 4000,
    open: true,
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the Webpack config above, you're not parsing anything from `node_modules`. The only issue I can see *might* be that this resolved path is incorrect (depends on where this configuration resides in relation to `node_modules`):

```
exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
```

At which point, all `node_modules` might be transpiled by `ts-loader` (and the other loaders) if the path is incorrect.

On that note, since you haven't set up a [less loader rule](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-webpack) in Webpack to handle antd less files, the only thing you'll be importing from the `antd` library would be the **unstyled** JS files.

For example, if you visit the [Your First Example](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Your-First-Example) within the antd documentation, you'll only see styled antd components when you `import "antd/dist/antd.css";`:
[image]

Otherwise, when you comment out the antd CSS import, the antd components become unstyled:
[image]

If you don't see the same result as above with your Webpack configuration, then it's likely that your `exclude` paths are incorrect or you have an import to `node_modules` within your code-base that points to a `style` directory within an antd component -- as is, none of the files within the root directory of a `date-picker` component (shown below) have an `import`/`require` statement that points to the `style` directory and, as a result, should be unstyled when imported within your code-base:

[image]